# Why use of references prevent decay of arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[3][3]
        = { { 3, 2, 7 }, { 2, 6, 8 }, { 5, 1, 9 } };

    for (auto& y : arr) {
        for (int x : y) {

            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code if we use `auto` instead of `auto&` the type becomes pointer to integer , while on using `auto&` the type is array of integers . Why this happens ? How References prevents decay of an array to pointers ?

the `auto&` could also have created a reference to pointer but why it is creating a reference to array ?

Comment: You probably mean `std::cout << x` instead of `std::cout << a[i][j]`. Your code as posted will not compile. Your problem is one of the reasons to use std::array<>.

Comment: "if we use auto instead of auto& the type becomes pointer to integer" -- what makes you believe this? How do you know that this is so?

Comment: For one, arrays can't be copied. So passing, returning or using arrays by value is impossible (unless wrapped inside a structure or class).

Comment: @MikeNakis https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nx5KsT4GW

Comment: *"the `auto&` could also have created a reference to pointer"* Reference to what pointer? A pointer resulting from decay is *computed*, it doesn't have a persistent memory location.

Comment: Even when you use capture by value you will get an int* `for (auto y : arr) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(y),int*>); }` taking that by reference makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

"Decay" of arrays to pointers happens as the result of two effects in C++:

1. Arrays cannot be copied, so `int array[] = other_array` is not valid, for example.
2. When necessary, arrays are converted to pointers via [array-to-pointer conversion](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.array#:conversion,array-to-pointer).

This means that `auto y = some_array`<sup>(1)</sup> necessitates array-to-pointer conversion. `y` is not a copy of the array since that isn't possible; it is a pointer. Or colloquially, the array "decays to a pointer".

However, the same does not apply to reference binding. References can bind to any type, including arrays. No copy is necessary, and no array-to-pointer conversion is requested. This means that in `auto& y = some_array`, `y` simply binds to some array.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> <sub>Such initialization of `y` to an array takes place in your range-based for loop. See [the cppreference article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for more information on what such a loop expands to.</sub>